# Cocoapods-Deintegrate from project results in SIGABRT Error

Tags: swift, cocoapods, sigabrt

Hey guys I uninstalled cocoa pods using [cocoapods-deintegrate](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate). I manually remove the pod, pods.lock and workspace. I also remove the imports that previously used pods. Opening the xCode project allows it to compile. When I run the app it results in a runtime error below. Any ideas how to fix this?

`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Do you get the error just by opening the project? Did you try cleaning the project and clearing derived data folder?

Comment: I am able to open the project. How do I clear the project? I didnt try clearing the derived data folder. It successfully compiles. Does that not overwrite the derived data folder contents for my app?

Comment: Cleaning the project will clean the build folder, and create a new build for you. Cmd+Shift+K would do that. Clearing Derived data helps usually. If it still fails, try pasting the whole error details.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.